# Adding method to instance of objective-c class at runtime

Tags: objective-c, runtime

I am wondering if there is a way to add an instance method to an "instance" of a class.

The scenario is that I am using EKEventEditViewController and there is a UITableView inside this class with a delegate(UITableViewDelegate) called "EKEventEditor" (non-public AFAIK).  It does not implements the tableView:willDisplayCell:forRowAtIndexPath: method, which I am trying to use to disable some cell.

So I am trying to add a method to the instance, but all I can find in the Obj-C runtime is the class_addMethod call which adds method to the class but not the instance.  With "EKEventEditor" being private, I can't just extend it and add that method myself.

Any hints?

Here is the code that I am using, the function that i am trying to add (willDisplayCell_) is not getting called.

```
- (void)navigationController:(UINavigationController *)navigationController 
  willShowViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController animated:(BOOL)animated {

if ([navigationController isKindOfClass:[EKEventEditViewController class]]) {

UITableViewController *rootController = (UITableViewController*)[(UINavigationController*)navigationController visibleViewController];
if ([rootController isKindOfClass:[UITableViewController class]]) {
  UITableView *eventTableView = (UITableView*)[rootController view];

  class_addMethod([eventTableView.delegate class], 
                  @selector(tableView:willDisplayCell:forRowAtIndexPath:), 
                  (IMP)willDisplayCell_, "v@:@@@");
}}} 


void willDisplayCell_(id self, SEL cmd, UITableView *tableView, UITableViewCell *cell, NSIndexPath *indexPath) {
  NSLog(@"CALLED?");
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This is totally possible, and amazingly useful](https://github.com/mralexgray/AtoZ.framework/blob/Core/AtoZ/Categories/NSObject-Utilities.h)...  Think altering the functionality of an instance without subclassing, etc...

```
@interface NSObject (AZOverride)
/** Dynamically overrides the specified method on this particular instance.
* The block's parameters and return type must match those of the method you 
* are overriding. However, the first parameter is always "id _self", which 
* points to the object itself.
* You do have to cast the block's type to (__bridge void *), e.g.:
*
*    [self az_overrideSelector:@selector(viewDidAppear:)
*            withBlock:(__bridge void *)^(id _self, BOOL animated) { ... }];
*/
- (BOOL)az_overrideSelector:(SEL)selector withBlock:(void *)block;
/** To call super from the overridden method, do the following:
*    SEL sel = @selector(viewDidAppear:);
*    void (*superIMP)(id, SEL, BOOL) = [_self az_superForSelector:sel];
*    superIMP(_self, sel, animated);
* This first gets a function pointer to the super method and then you call it.
*/
- (void *)az_superForSelector:(SEL)selector;
@end
```

Answer (score 3):

That's the function you want. That will add the (instance) method to *all instances* of the class.* There's no way to add a method just to one particular instance.**

You might want to look into using a [Category](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Chapters/ocCategories.html), however, which *does* let you extend a class whose `@implementation` you don't control. This will only work if you can import the class's primary `@interface`, though, and it sounds like that may not be the case.

---

*If you wanted to add a class method, you would call the function with the metaclass as the first argument.

**Barring some trickery with overriding `forwardInvocation:` and possibly libffi, which I'm working on.

Comment: You could add a method to one particular instance using the same subclass-and-swizzle trickery that KVO uses to dynamically override the accessors of individual objects.

Comment: @JoshCaswell  I edited the question with my code, am I doing something wrong such that willDisplayCell_ is not called?

Comment: @Herman: I'm not sure. That looks right to me. It may be that the table view isn't sending that message, since it assumes that its delegate doesn't implement it.

Comment: @JoshCaswell sorry didn't see the comment until now.  hm.... any trickery you think I can do to make this work?

Comment: @Herman: You should definitely put a breakpoint on `[<#Whatever the class of the delegate is#> tableView:willDisplayCell:forRowAtIndexPath:]` to check that out. If it isn't getting sent, I don't know what you could (reasonably) do. You'd have to swap the `eventTableView` out for your own object -- likely to be extremely difficult. That would probably be worth its own SO question, though; I'm sure someone would have an idea or two.

Comment: @JoshCaswell, yeah, I don't think I can set the bp since EKEventEditor is private.  I'll post another SO question, thanks for getting back!

Answer (score 2):

Here is [REKit](https://github.com/zuccoi/REKit) for you. It gives you ability to add/override method at instance level.

With REKit, you can add the method to `eventTableView.delegate` like below:

```
[eventTableView.delegate
    respondsToSelector:@selector(tableView:willDisplayCell:forRowAtIndexPath:)
    withKey:nil
    usingBlock:^(id receiver, UITableView *tableView, UITableViewCell *cell, NSIndexPath *indexPath) {
        // Do something…
    }
];
```